# Can I use <include file="..."/> in a Liquibase rollback section?

Tags: liquibase

I couldn't immediately see, in the current documentation I am looking at:

**Will the following work in Liquibase, and use the included SQL file for the rollback?**

```
<changeSet author="username" id="85138">
    <sql splitStatements="false">
        UPDATE some_table ...;
    </sql>
    <rollback>
        <include file="path/to/rollback.sql"/>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

If I've missed the appropriate spot in the documentation, feel free to point out the relevant section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you can do is use sqlFile:

```
<changeset ..>
  <sql>...</sql>
  <rollback>
    <sqlFile path="rollback.sql" />
  </rollback>
</changeset>
```

As mentioned by another post, include is used for changelog composition only - to include other changelogs.

Comment: And here's the documentation for the `sqlFile` tag: http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql_file

Comment: @Mirko .. so if i made 10 changes forward with changesets, each of the 10 changes in its own changeset , the DatabaseChangeLog table will have 10 entries. Using the rollback sqlfile approach above.. will the 10 records from the table get deleted when i run the rollback command?

Answer (score 0):

No, that will not work. The include tag is intended for including further changelog XML files, not for including arbitrary information.

It's documented here: http://www.liquibase.org/manual/include

It doesn't say you "can't" specifically, but I tried it - and liquibase will yell at you for it. =)

Comment: This is technically correct, given the question, but see @Mirko's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12772067/26196), and this documentation: http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql_file